# How to test if an imported Promise was called by the tested function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a function to test with Jest, which calls some Promises from another module. I mocked out these Promises, but `.toBeCalled()` always reports they were never called. I'm probably doing it wrong.

The tested function is doing something like this:

```
import { externalPromise } from '@helpers';

export const functionToTest = () => {
  return await externalPromise();
}
```

This is how I'm trying to test it:

```
import { externalPromise } from '@helpers';
import { functionToTest } from './whatever';

jest.mock('@helpers', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@helpers'),
  externalPromise: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve())
}));

it('should call externalPromise', () => {

  functionToTest();

  expect(externalPromise).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The calls to `externalPromise` is always 0. How can I test if it was called or not?

Comment: A promise doesn't get 'called' because it's not a function. What *exactly* are you trying to detect. If the `.then()` function is getting called?

Comment: I am trying to test if the line where the function executes the promise. In the real function it should not happen when there's an error.

Comment: there might be a misunderstanding here then. Promises have an 'executor' that are usually responsible for setting up the resolve/reject events but by the time you get a promise, the executor is already done.